# User values from select statement and insert into DB

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will return set is results and then use these results to insert into a database, I know how do this this individually but not as a combined stored procedure: 
[image: table image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_userlist (assocuser, userID)
SELECT @id, ID
FROM tbl_login
WHERE type = 'user' and assocuser = @userid
```

For your edit, it looks like you want to use [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Here's a basic UNPIVOT example, modified straight from the MSDN UNPIVOT example:

```
SELECT ID, AssocUser, UserID
FROM tbl_login
UNPIVOT
   (UserID FOR Col IN 
      (User1, User2)
)AS unpvt;
```

You should be able to expand it from there.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  You want to get all the userIDs from tbl_userlist as a horizontal list?  Is this coming back to an application or is this going to just be run in SQL?

Comment: within the SQL stored procedure itself.

Comment: Explain what you want the stored procedure to do.

Comment: From where does the data for the returned record originate?  Can you give an example of how you would get the data (forget the formatting, just get the data)?  Edit your question to include all this information so that people can see what you're asking.

Comment: That helped a lot.  Try UNPIVOT (linked in my updated answer).

Comment: Thanks Zimdanen, I tried using the UNPIVOT using the reference to the provided in the MS example, but cannot get this working as in the example the fields are of the same column name but in my example the column names are all different.  SELECT assocuser, User1LoginID, User2LoginID, User3LoginID, User4LoginID, User5LoginID, User6LoginID, User8LoginID, User7LoginID, User9LoginID, User10LoginID FROM tbl_login Where assocuser=@ID Unpivot PackageLoginID,User1LoginID,User2LoginID,User3LoginID, User4LoginID,User5LoginID,User6LoginID,User8LoginID, User7LoginID,User9LoginID,User10LoginID

Comment: Added an example; you should be able to expand from there.